# Increase encryption level to 128-bit for password pdf protection with CAM::PDF

Tags: bash, perl, pdf

I have been using CAM::PDF perl module for password protection of pdf documents, The default encryption level is 40-bit.
This is not very strong. Is it possible to increase this to at least 128-bit?
I am looking for command line tool that can be used in Linux or Windows with perl.

There is is paid tool verypdf which does this, but before purchasing this want to make sure
if there is perl/open source way to do it without using commercial apps.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 3):

[pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) seems to support either 40-bit or 128-bit encryption.